# Constructor call

Tags: java, constructor

I have three classes:

```
public class A {
    public A(){
        System.out.println("in A");
    }
}


public class B extends A{

    public B(){
        System.out.println("in b");
    }
} 


public class C extends B{

    public C(){
        System.out.println("in C");
    }   
}
```

Now I am really not sure how the constructor calls work.
If I instantiate `C c= new C();`, in what order (and why that order) does the constructors get called.
If I instantiate the class C, then should not it just check if the class C has got any constructor or not and if it does, it shall use it?

Why does it output-> In A  In B  In C?

Doesn't it go up in the hierarchy only when it doesn't find the constructor in it's own class? Or the constructors of the super class are called implicitly every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super constructor are called by default from the base class constructor.

The only case in which you should call a super class constructor with super, is when you need to explicitly pass a parameter to the super class constructor itself.

So the answer is yes, they are all called. The order is from the most up class in the hierarchy down to the base class, so : A, B, C.

Answer (score 2):

Default constructors are always invoked, and are invoked top-down - from the topmost super-class to the lowest base-class.

Note that the `super(...)` call is necessary only for parameterized constructors. In your case you don't have any, so the default gets called automatically.

Answer (score 1):

When a constructor is invoked, it first calls `super()`, so though the stack trace will show: C->B->A, actually A will be invoked first and C will be invoked last, thus the printing will show:

```
in A
in B
in C
```

Comment: That "actually A will be invoked first" wording is misleading. The constructor for C is called first, because you're initialising an instance of type C. The print order is caused by the control flow for the constructors up the hierarchy, not because the constructor for A gets called first.

Comment: @Anthony: I tried to explain this idea in my answer, if you have a better term I will gladly use it, unfortunately english is not my native tongue.. :\

Answer (score 0):

`super()` is implicit, as the default constructors if no constructors declared.

The constructors run upwards:

```
C calls B, B calls A, A calls to Object that does nothing and return to A, then outputs and return the flow to B, that outputs and return to C that outputs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Super constructor is called by default. It is executed prior to any lines of code in the derived class's constructor. So if you call new C(), A's constructor is run, then B's, then anything in C's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you not define any constructor it will implicitly create the default construct and call it. Now when you extends any class then like class C it go with its constructor but there it didn't find to call the super class explicitly so the compiler implicitly call the super class constructor. that why when we call the super class constructor that statement always first like this way

```
public C(){
   super();
}
```

if you write any statement before calling the super class constructor you getting error

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Java language specification

> "If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body is implicitly assumed by the compiler to begin with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments."

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#41652

Answer (score 0):

Class A is the super class for B and class B is super class of C. That means A is at the top position among them, where B is in top for C, next to A and C is sitting bottom of B. So class A execute first and then B and then C. It's like some priority in Java for super classes.